# Stop a user from performing UNION operation on Database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Is there any way i can stop a user to perform a UNION operation on my Database ?

Comment: Don't let users submit arbitrary SQL statements to your database.

Comment: use prepared statements and read up on sql injections …

Comment: @clintp: Now how do i do that ?
for eg: I am providing a textbox for a user to put in his queries, that will execute on my system.

Comment: if thats the case, check the text box for the union keyword and pop up a message saying that he cannot do that.

Comment: @knittl: I want him to execute everything, injections too.. just stop him from entering a UNION query. actually i have to do this for making a demo application that is hackable, and one of the requirement of my teacher is that he doesn't want UNION queries to run, although he is fine with other SQL injections. I know its strange, but can't help.

Comment: They can cheat: print the results of two queries on a same sheet of paper.

Comment: Why the close request? This is a very weird question of course but it's answerable, not subjective and by no means an offtopic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could build an `EXPLAIN` for the query prior to running it and reject the query if there is a mention of `UNION` in `select_type`.

This wouldn't allow you to run any `DML` queries, though, since `EXPLAIN` does not work on them.

Not that I have any idea why on Earth would you need to do that.

Comment: have to look into that, but seems that something can be done :)

Answer (score 3):

Not that I'd recommend this, but...

```
if (stripos($_POST['query'],'union') !== false) die("No dice, bro.")
```

This would obviously have the unwanted side effect of not allowing your user to put the word "union" in any database field without doing something silly like `concat('un','ion')`.

Comment: I'm not a php guy, but make sure you catch upper and lowercase strings.

Comment: @Remy yes, `stripos` is [case-insensitive](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php).

Comment: @arihant yes, another unwanted side effect.  (Hence the disclaimer.)

Comment: @Arihant - the solutions provided give you the exact idea - write some code - then you can check what you want.  if you need a special case where your string is also part of a table name, then you can spend alot of time parsing SQL into a parse tree, or you can hack some string checks - you get to make up the rules in the hack version... go for it.

Answer (score 0):

I would basically support reggie. Alternativly you could only scan the input string for the word UNION. Just be aware that this is in any case a security risk.